# How to use Exclude in FluentAssertions for property in collection of collections?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, fluent-assertions

I have two records:

```
public record A(string AId, IReadOnlyList<B> list)

public record B(string BId, string Color)
```

I want to use fluent assertions to compare collections of instances of A, while excluding the proberty `BId`

e.g:
Let's say I have

`FirstCollection = {{AId:"AId1", BId:"BId1 ,Color:"Red"} ,{AId:"AId2", BId:"BId2", Color:"Red"}}`

`SecondCollection = {{AId:"AId1", BId:"BId3", Color:"Red"} ,{AId:"AId2", BId:"BId4", Color:"Red"}}`

Asserting the following two collections should pass.

Comment: Can you give an example? If I undertand you correctly, you want to make sure that two instances have the same string AId, and all elements of list have the same Color, but may have different BIds?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Added an example if that helps

Comment: Please include a
[minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It's difficult to help you, if we have to guess your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Excluding` method, something like this:

```
expected.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(actual, options => options.Excluding(s => 
   (s.RuntimeType == typeof(B)) && (s.PropertyPath.EndsWith("BId")));
```

https://github.com/fluentassertions/fluentassertions/issues/500

Comment: Didn't work. I think it might have to do with the fact that I am asserting a collection of A's. So the configuration here were added to instance's of A which does not have BId.

Comment: @omarkh You need to change this line based on what you are exactly looking for, it is hard to provide a working answer without seeing your code.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. I want to compare two collections of instances of A's. where each instance's of A should have the same AId and color but does not have to be the same BId.
Added an example if that helps

Comment: @omarkh Please try this and let me know if it works `expected.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(actual, options =>
  options.Excluding(s => (Regex.IsMatch(s.SelectedMemberPath, "list\\[.+\\].BId"));`

Comment: Didn't work also. Tried to override equal on class B without comparing the BId's and the assertion worked. I would say the Excluding method didn't work as expected in your code

Comment: Are you familiar with a way where I can override the B class equal's for the tests only?